# Loop section of script

Tags: loops, powershell

```
mode con: cols=52 lines=16
while ($script -ne "Q") {
$tag = ""
while (-not ($tag)) {
$tag = Read-Host 'Enter tag # or Q to quit'
$date = get-date -f MM-dd-yyyy_HH_mm_ss
$username = [Environment]::Username 

if(!(Test-Path -path "C:\Users\$username\Desktop\PSTools\Screenshot Dump\")) {
New-Item "C:\Users\$username\Desktop\PSTools\Screenshot Dump\" -type directory
}

}

if ($tag -eq "Q"){break}

cls

#$ErrorActionPreference = 'silentlycontinue'

cd "C:\Users\$username\Desktop\PSTools"

set-alias psexec "C:\Users\$username\Desktop\PSTools\PsExec.exe"

set-alias nircmd "C:\Users\$username\Desktop\PSTools\nircmd.exe"

------>LOOP START HERE

psexec \\$tag -i -c -s nircmd savescreenshotfull "C:\$tag-$date.png"

move "\\$tag\c$\$tag-$date.png" "C:\Users\$username\Desktop\PSTools\Screenshot Dump\$tag-$date.png"

explorer "C:\Users\$username\Desktop\PSTools\Screenshot Dump\$tag-$date.png"

------>LOOP END HERE

"`n"
}
```

Basically I'm trying to loop where I have stated above, but I'm use to doing it in command prompt and it's not the same. I want to make it loop X amount of times or until I CTRL+C to quit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use a Foreach loop.
Let's say you want to loop 5 times :

```
$NumberOfLoops = 5
Foreach ($loop in (1..$NumberOfLoops)) { Do Loopy Stuff }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a basic FOR statement to loop.  Although, PowerShell has some great looping techniques.  It's worth a look through...

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4542.powershell-loops.aspx

For an example of a basic FOR loop, just do as so (will loop 10 times ($x=0-9)):

```
FOR ($x=0; $x -lt 10; $x++) { DO LOOPY STUFF };
```

Comment: The other benefit is that `for` is a statement, not a cmdlet, so an interrupt will actually break out. When using ForEach-Object, you end up with craziness required to bust out of a pipline